# How to make costum switch button in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-switch, android-designer

I'm trying to do something like that in Android,
is there any way?
[image]

I searched a lot but with no success.

Thank You.

Comment: You basically don't want to do that as this is not an Android design

Comment: is there any alternative solutions? something that the user can select from.

Comment: This is generally what you use to activate/deactivate options in your app settings on Android: [Material Design - Selection controls](https://material.io/guidelines/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch)

Comment: I want it to select from different options, not for activate and deactivate

Answer (score 1):

[Android-segmented-control](https://github.com/Kaopiz/android-segmented-control) library maybe the solution for you . It  is inspired   Segmented Controls for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Check Out Radio Buttons it's basically the same thing you can learn more here,

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html